# Set Image of Custom UIView from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, xib

I am trying to create an app like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [topmobiletrends.com](http://topmobiletrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/screen568x568-14.jpeg))</sub>

where each of the views show an image for every in a photo in a JSON array.

I have successfully set and downloaded the array of images and set them in a `UIImageView` with with `NSURLRequest` and `SDWebImage`.

I created a `UIView` with an image view inside to test the code in my `ViewController(Storyboard)`, everything works fine. However, when I try to create a `UIView` to loop programmatically, it shows up blank, with no `ImageView`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code for my `ViewController.m`

```
for (NSObject *photo in photos) {

     UIView *dView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,250,258,229)];
        dView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        myImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

        //Get image from url
        [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
        [self.myImage addSubview:imageView];

        priceLabel.text = [[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"site"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"price"];
        [imageView addSubview:dView];

    });
        }

        }];

[task resume];

   }
```

Comment: why you are creating a new UIView for every image?

Comment: @raki Would it be better to create a reusable xib (custom UIView) instead?

Comment: once observe my answer below....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding dView as subview for your image view may be it  is `[dView addSubview:imageView];`

Comment: Just tried it, the views are still showing up blank. :(

Comment: Now the views show an image, but every view is showing the same image. I need each view to show a new image for each object in the array.

Comment: Actually it works now! :) In addition to your solution I removed an unnecessary for loop prior to the one shown, and all the images passed! :) Thanks for helping me. I wish I could +1, but I need 5 more reputations. :/

Answer (score 0):

try this. the main issue is you are not setting frame for image view

```
 for (NSObject *photo in photos) {
    //UIView *dView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,250,258,229)];
    //dView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,250,258,229)];
    [self.myImage addSubview:imageView];

    priceLabel.text = [[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"site"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"price"];
    //[imageView addSubview:dView];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (imgData) {
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
            }
        });
    });
    }
```

Comment: The views are still showing up blank. :( No image view OR label (priceLabel).

Comment: see whether your url is propper

Comment: Yeah the url is fine. It shows up on the view I created in Storyboard. But the other views, nothing.